# Identify this movie where dimensional compression technology is used by thief to sheath swords inside their chests.

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie is not older than 2006. Some kind of Ninjas where stealing something from a vault. The interesting thing was they kept their swords inside their chests with some kind of dimensional compression technology (flat-space). They had a little box in their chests. Dimensions where about 3cmX2cmX2cm. The swords got perpendicularly in to their bodies without hurting them. They stole something from a vault and one of them got killed the others ran away with the bounty.

I tried to look for it in Google and Wikipedia, but I just keep finding *Ultraviolet* references. It is not *Ultraviolet*.

Comment: Are you sure it's not ultraviolet? http://moa.omnimulti.com/Flat-Space_technology. Basically you're describing the opening scene from that film. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wpjpuu1LrOU

Comment: Thanks for the attention but please read the post, it was the first thing i tried to clear up. No, it is not the same movie. There are not ninjas hiding Katana swords in their chests in Ultraviolet. I keep receiving references to Ultraviolet because is the most memorable movie with that kind of technology. The ninjas im talking about had a little box in their chests. Dimensions where about 3cmX2cmX2cm. The swords got perpendicularly in to their bodies without hurting them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would have to agree with Richard's comment. You described the opening scene of *Ultraviolet* perfectly, I just watched the first 2 minutes of the movie to verify that. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to respond as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the attention but please read the post, it was the first thing i tried to clear up. No, it is not the same movie. There are not ninjas hiding Katana swords in their chests in Ultraviolet. I keep receiving references to Ultraviolet because is the most memorable movie with that kind of technology. The ninjas im talking about had a little box in their chests. Dimensions where about 3cmX2cmX2cm. The swords got perpendicularly in to their bodies without hurting them.

Comment: Here is where i have to decide to delete the post, just like Homer Simpson discussing about Don Quixote, or be brave and accept i was wrong.

Yesterday before posting, i downloaded the movie again, but i didn't note it jumps to minute 7.39 every time. So i was very sure it wasn't. Today after so many people pointing it out, i downloaded it again and there it is.

Funny thing about how mind works is that i remembered the thieves running away, and i was almost sure that the actors, of the later conversation between the investigators, were Laurence Fishburne and Elias Koteas. Fake memory.

Comment: @Cobalto -- Meh; don't delete it -- it could be helpful to someone else with the same question.. And we've all (well, I know **I** have) done the same thing before... "What was X, and I know it wasn't Y", and it turns out it WAS Y after all...

Comment: :)...of course, i won't delete it... funny thing is i was pretty upset, even my friends insisted it was ultraviolet, but i had seen the movie 5minutes before!! and didnt see that scene!... it is amazing how your mind plays with you. I was getting insane trying to remember where i saw that.